# How to aggregate ruby hash based on value of some keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given an array of hashes

```
arr = [{'city' => 'Bangalore','device' => 'desktop','users' => '20'},
       {'city' => 'Bangalore','device' => 'tablet','users' => '20'},
       {'city' => 'Bangalore','device' => 'mobile','users' => '20'},
       {'city' => 'Pune','device' => 'desktop','users' => '20'},
       {'city' => 'Pune','device' => 'tablet','users' => '20'},
       {'city' => 'Pune','device' => 'mobile','users' => '20'},
       {'city' => 'Mumbai','device' => 'desktop','users' => '20'},
       {'city' => 'Mumbai','device' => 'tablet','users' => '20'},
       {'city' => 'Mumbai','device' => 'mobile','users' => '20'}]
```

How can I produce the following array of hashes?

```
[{'city' => 'Bangalore', 'users' => '60'},
 {'city' => 'Pune', 'users' => '60'},
 {'city' => 'Mumbai','users' => '60'}]
```

Comment: is this active record object?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's not active record, I have used each loop and built a new object, but I like to know a better way

Comment: In other words, you want to sum up the user counts for each city and throw away the `device` keys?

Comment: In editing (to make the totals work), I assumed the next-to-last hash in the array was for Mumbai, not  Pune, so I changed "Pune" to "Mumbai". It would be better to have a variety of values for "users", rather than all of them being "20".

Answer (score 0):

Do it like :

```
hash = [{'city' => 'Bangalore','device' => 'desktop','users' => '20'}, {'city' => 'Bangalore','device' => 'tablet','users' => '20'}, {'city' => 'Bangalore','device' => 'mobile','users' => '20'}, {'city' => 'Pune','device' => 'desktop','users' => '20'},
 {'city' => 'Pune','device' => 'tablet','users' => '20'}, {'city' => 'Pune','device' => 'mobile','users' => '20'}, {'city' => 'Mumbai','device' => 'desktop','users' => '20'},
 {'city' => 'Pune','device' => 'tablet','users' => '20'}, {'city' => 'Mumbai','device' => 'mobile','users' => '20'}]   

new_hash = hash.map{|obj| {:city => obj[:city], :users => obj[:users]}}
```

Comment: "hash" is perhaps not the best name for an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def setter hash, hash_array_new
  new_hash = {}
  new_hash["users"] = hash["users"].to_i
  new_hash["city"] = hash["city"]
  hash_array_new << new_hash
end

hash_array_new = []
hash_array.each do |hash|
  count = 0
  hash_array_new.each do |new_hash|
    if hash["city"] == new_hash["city"]
      new_hash["users"] += hash["users"].to_i
      count = count+1
    end
  end
  if count == 0
    setter hash, hash_array_new
  end
  if hash_array_new.blank?
    setter hash, hash_array_new
  end
end


puts hash_array_new //display resultant array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g["city"]] += g["users"].to_i }.
    map { |city,users| { 'city' => city, 'users' => users.to_s } }
  #=> [{"city"=>"Bangalore", "users"=>"60"},
  #    {"city"=>"Pune", "users"=>"60"},
  #    {"city"=>"Mumbai", "users"=>"60"}]
```

`Hash.new(0)` is sometimes referred to as a counting hash. Zero is the default value. (See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).) This means that for

```
h[g["city"]] += g["users"].to_i
```

which expands to

```
h[g["city"]] = h[g["city"]] + g["users"].to_i
```

`h[g["city"]]` on the right side is replaced with the default value of zero when `h` does not have a key `g["city"]`.

Note that

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g["city"]] += g["users"].to_i }
  #=> {"Bangalore"=>60, "Pune"=>60, "Mumbai"=>60}
```